# How to play a sound file Safari with web audio API?

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, safari, web-audio-api

I'm modifying a script to play an mp3 that I found on Codepen to get it to work on Safari. In Firefox and Chrome it works fine, but Safari complains : "Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Not enough arguments
index.html:25"

I've read https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds.html That goes into much more advanced stuff than I need. I just want to play the sound in my mp3. I need web audio though, because that is the only way to get it to work on iOS Safari.

Does anyone know how to make Safari happy?

https://codepen.io/kslstn/full/pagLqL

```js
(function () {
    
  if('AudioContext' in window || 'webkitAudioContext' in window) {  
    // Check for the web audio API. Safari requires the webkit prefix.


  const URL = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/Yodel_Sound_Effect.mp3';
    
  var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
  var context = new AudioContext(); // Make it crossbrowser    
      
  const playButton = document.querySelector('#play');
    
  let yodelBuffer;

  window.fetch(URL)
    .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
    .then(arrayBuffer => context.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))
    .then(audioBuffer => {
      yodelBuffer = audioBuffer;
    });
    
    playButton.onclick = () => play(yodelBuffer);

  function play(audioBuffer) {
    const source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start();
  }

}

}());
```

```html
<button id="play">Yodel!</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Promise-based syntax for BaseAudioContext.decodeAudioData() is not supported in Safari(Webkit). See detailed browser compatibility in the following link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData

So you need to use the old callback syntax as below. It works in both Safari higher than 6.0 and Chrome higher than 10

```
window.fetch(URL)
  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(arrayBuffer => context.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, 
                                               audioBuffer => {
                                                 yodelBuffer = audioBuffer;
                                                }, 
                                               error => 
                                               console.error(error)
                                              ))
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot. Weirdly, Safari on iOS plays the file with distortion and noise, but that's a whole other issue.

Comment: With distortion and noise? Maybe it is the audio decoding issue

Comment: It’s super weird, it only happened twice and only when playing the sound the first time after loading the page. Not even entirely sure if it’s not caused by pocket lint in my headphone jack. But then the second time it sounded good. Anyway, I need to do more testing and see how I can reproduce it.

Comment: I do the same but for me, sometimes audio playing in low volume, and all of a sudden volume getting increased. Another weird thing is sometimes the audio is not audible and after refreshing the page it's working. 

@yueyou